# Evento onExit em editText?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Estou procurando um evento chamado *onExit* no *editText*, mas não encontrei nenhum.

O que eu quero fazer é adicionar um função ao sair do campo.

Ex 1.: O usuário está usando um leitor de código de barras `bluetooth` e quando ele lê o código, o leitor já passa para outro campo(com `TAB` configurado no leitor de código de barras) e já carrega os dados relacionados a aquele código.

Ex 2.: Ao adicionar o CEP quando o usuário selecionar outro campo o sistema já carrega automaticamente outros sem pressionar botão algum.

Ex. Em codigo:
Trocar o botão "translateButton" para o editText e o evento "Click" para o que eu não econtrei que é o "onExit".

```
translateButton.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
{
    Core.PhonewordTranslator.ToNumber(phoneNumberText.Text);   // Translate user's alphanumeric phone number to numeric translatedNumber =
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(translatedNumber)) 
        { 
            callButton.Text = "Call"; callButton.Enabled = false; 
        } 
    else 
        { 
            callButton.Text = "Call " + translatedNumber; callButton.Enabled = true; 
        } 
};
```

Se alguém souber de algo parecido, favor me ajudem.

Answer (score 0):

No xamarin forms o Entry tem um evento chamado Unfocused entao voce pode implementar a função 
campo.Unfocused += (object sender, FocusEventArgs e) =>{
  //implementar
}
Se tem para Xamarin Forms, com certeza tem para Android.

Answer (score 0):

Eu usaria o próprio atributo do Android, o `FocusChangeListener`. Em Xamarin, pode colocar algo assim:

```cs
translateButton.FocusChange += (sender, e) => {
  if ( e.HasFocus ) {
    //ganhou foco
  }
  else {
    //perdou o foco
  }
}
```